# How to get href link from list using selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

Here is the code of the web

[image]

The xpath of search-results-list container grid is

```
 //[@id="product_type_products_list"]/div/div[2]/div
```

and the xpath of result is

```
 //*[@id="product_type_products_list"]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]
```

I have try using :

```
elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="product_type_products_list"]/div/div[2]/div')
url = driver.find_element_by_link_text(elems[0].text).get_attribute("href")
print(url)
```

this give the link to the beginning of the web.

Thank you for your consideration.

Answer (score 1):

Try Narrowing it down to the <'A> Tag by appending the xpath like so:

```
elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('.//*[@id="product_type_products_list"]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/a')
```

Then just retrieve the href attribute like you did earlier but using the same element:

```
url = elems[0].get_attribute("href")
```

Comment: in your answer, `elems` is a list of elements, which does not have a `get_attribute` method.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out Corey. I added the index in there.

Answer (score 1):

The code you've provided doesn't look like a valid HTML to me, however you can try the following XPath expression:

```
//div[@class='result']/descendant::a
```

[image]

More information:

- [XPath Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp)
- [XPath Axes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes)
- [XPath Functions and Operators](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=40044727)

Comment: I don't know whether i can post like this,i edited the question anywhere thank for your help.